# ERROR: function add(integer, integer) does not exist No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: postgresql, regression-testing, postgresql-extensions

I have tried various ways to solve this issue:
i tried it with the code `SELECT add(1, 2);` but still getting the same result. I have looked at other stack overflow asnwers but they are not working either.

```sql
-- Test the add function
SELECT add(1::int, 2::int);
ERROR:  function add(integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT add(1::int, 2::int);
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What changes should i make to the my_extension--regress.sql to fix this as the add function is working just fine in the psql db spartacus:

```
spartacus=# SELECT add(3,5)                                                                                                                        ;
 add
-----
   8
(1 row)
```

The code of the various files are given below:

## CODE:

### my_extension--1.0.sql:

```sql
-- Create necessary objects for version 1.0
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

-- Add 2 numbers using add function
CREATE FUNCTION add(a integer, b integer) RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
    RETURN a + b;
```

### my_extension--regress.sql:

```sql
-- regression test script for my_extension
-- Create the my_table table
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

-- Delete existing rows from my_table
DELETE FROM my_table;

-- Verify the data in the my_table table
SELECT * FROM my_table;

-- Test the add function
SELECT add(1::int, 2::int);
```

After running the make insatll funtion getting error:

```
echo "+++ regress install-check in  +++" && /Users/spartacus/.pgenv/pgsql-15.0/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/test/regress/pg_regress --inputdir=./ --bindir='/Users/spartacus/.pgenv/pgsql-15.0/bin'    --dbname=contrib_regression my_extension--regress
+++ regress install-check in  +++
(using postmaster on Unix socket, default port)
============== dropping database "contrib_regression" ==============
SET
DROP DATABASE
============== creating database "contrib_regression" ==============
CREATE DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
============== running regression test queries        ==============
test my_extension--regress        ... FAILED       17 ms

======================
 1 of 1 tests failed.
======================

The differences that caused some tests to fail can be viewed in the
file "/Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension/regression.diffs".  A copy of the test summary that you see
above is saved in the file "/Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension/regression.out".

make: *** [installcheck] Error 1
```

### my_extension--regress.out:

```
-- regression test script for my_extension
-- Create the my_table table
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
-- Delete existing rows from my_table
DELETE FROM my_table;
-- Verify the data in the my_table table
SELECT * FROM my_table;
 id | name 
----+------
(0 rows)

-- Test the add function
SELECT add(1::int, 2::int);
ERROR:  function add(integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT add(1::int, 2::int);
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: You didn't run `CREATE EXTENSION` in your regression test script, so the extension does not exist. That explains why the `add` function doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regression file is wrong:

#### `my_extension--regress.out`:

```sql
-- regression test script for my_extension
CREATE EXTENSION my_extension;

-- Verify the data in the my_table table
SELECT * FROM my_table;

-- Test the add function
SELECT add(1, 2);
```

As pointed out be Laurenz Albe:
Didn't run CREATE EXTENSION in your regression test script, so the extension does not exist. Because of which the add function doesn't exist.